# 401 (Unauthorized) error with jwt in iframe only production, not testing env

Tags: iframe, extjs, jwt

In testing env, the page in iframe is loaded successfully. However, in production, it's not working with 401 (unauthorized error)

the error message in console is `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()`

UI framework: ExtJs

```
{
  Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
    id: 'iframe',
    anchor: '100%, 100%',
    autoEl: {
      tag: 'iframe',
      src: 'about:blank'
    }
  }
}
```

And then, call an api to get src url with token

```
var jwtToken = CreateFunction();
var url = baseurl + "?auth-token=" + jwtToken
return response() 
  {
    IsSuccessful = true;
    reponseUrl = url;
  }
```

After that, set iframe's src url with `responeUrl` from api.

This issue exists in different browsers.
The url is working in a different tab or window.

Not sure where should look into it to resolve the issue since it's working in testing env.

Do you have any idea?